# Pandas create new column with count from groupby

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df that looks like the following:

```
id        item        color
01        truck       red
02        truck       red
03        car         black
04        truck       blue
05        car         black
```

I am trying to create a df that looks like this:

```
item      color       count
truck     red          2
truck     blue         1
car       black        2
```

I have tried

```
df["count"] = df.groupby("item")["color"].transform('count')
```

But it is not quite what I am searching for.

Any guidance is appreciated

Comment: Related: [Python Pandas Create New Column with Groupby().Sum()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30244952/python-pandas-create-new-column-with-groupby-sum) (see also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54417351/4909087) which applies to your scenario)

Answer (score 141, accepted):

That's not a new column, that's a new DataFrame:

```
In [11]: df.groupby(["item", "color"]).count()
Out[11]:
             id
item  color
car   black   2
truck blue    1
      red     2
```

To get the result you want is to use `reset_index`:

```
In [12]: df.groupby(["item", "color"])["id"].count().reset_index(name="count")
Out[12]:
    item  color  count
0    car  black      2
1  truck   blue      1
2  truck    red      2
```

To get a "new column" you could use transform:

```
In [13]: df.groupby(["item", "color"])["id"].transform("count")
Out[13]:
0    2
1    2
2    2
3    1
4    2
dtype: int64
```

I recommend reading the [split-apply-combine section of the docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html).

Comment: This is great thanks! Had never seen the split-apply-combine page before.

Comment: The `name` argument is deprecated in later versions of Python, I think. I got an error message, in any case.

Comment: I am wondering why in the API reference of Pandas "name" is not mentioned among possible arguments for reset_index: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html

Comment: DataFrame.reset_index() doesn't support `name` as keyword argument anymore, use `names` instead since pandas 1.5.0

Answer (score 32):

Another possible way to achieve the desired output would be to use [Named Aggregation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html#named-aggregation). Which will allow you to specify the name and respective aggregation function for the desired output columns.

> ## Named aggregation
>
> (*New in version 0.25.0.*)
>
> To support column-specific aggregation with control over the output
>   column names, pandas accepts the special syntax in `GroupBy.agg()`,
>   known as “named aggregation”, where:
>
> - The keywords are the output column names
> - The values are tuples whose first element is the column to select and
>     the second element is the aggregation to apply to that column. Pandas
>     provides the `pandas.NamedAgg` named tuple with the fields `['column','aggfunc']` to make it clearer what the arguments are. As usual, the
>     aggregation can be a callable or a string alias.

So to get the desired output - you could try something like...

```
import pandas as pd
# Setup
df = pd.DataFrame([
    {
        "item":"truck",
        "color":"red"
    },
    {
        "item":"truck",
        "color":"red"
    },
    {
        "item":"car",
        "color":"black"
    },
    {
        "item":"truck",
        "color":"blue"
    },
    {
        "item":"car",
        "color":"black"
    }
])

df_grouped = df.groupby(["item", "color"]).agg(
    count_col=pd.NamedAgg(column="color", aggfunc="count")
)
print(df_grouped)
```

Which produces the following output:

```
             count_col
item  color
car   black          2
truck blue           1
      red            2
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use [`value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.value_counts.html) and name the column with [`reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
In [3]: df[['item', 'color']].value_counts().reset_index(name='counts')
Out[3]: 
    item  color  counts
0    car  black       2
1  truck    red       2
2  truck   blue       1
```

Comment: Just a quick heads-up: the argument inside .reset_index() should be *name* (singular), not names.

Answer (score 5):

Here is another option:

```
import numpy as np
df['Counts'] = np.zeros(len(df))
grp_df = df.groupby(['item', 'color']).count()
```

which results in

```
             Counts
item  color        
car   black       2
truck blue        1
      red         2
```

Answer (score 2):

An option that is more literal then the accepted answer.

```
df.groupby(["item", "color"], as_index=False).agg(count=("item", "count"))
```

Any column name can be used in place of "item" in the aggregation.

"as_index=False" prevents the grouped column from becoming the index.

Comment: This works great when all the columns need to be part of the group.