# pandas add column to groupby dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have this simple dataframe `df`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'c':[1,1,1,2,2,2,2],'type':['m','n','o','m','m','n','n']})
```

my goal is to count values of `type` for each `c`, and then add a column with the size of `c`. So starting with:

```
In [27]: g = df.groupby('c')['type'].value_counts().reset_index(name='t')

In [28]: g
Out[28]: 
   c type  t
0  1    m  1
1  1    n  1
2  1    o  1
3  2    m  2
4  2    n  2
```

the first problem is solved. Then I can also:

```
In [29]: a = df.groupby('c').size().reset_index(name='size')

In [30]: a
Out[30]: 
   c  size
0  1     3
1  2     4
```

How can I add the `size` column directly to the first dataframe? So far I used `map` as:

```
In [31]: a.index = a['c']

In [32]: g['size'] = g['c'].map(a['size'])

In [33]: g
Out[33]: 
   c type  t  size
0  1    m  1     3
1  1    n  1     3
2  1    o  1     3
3  2    m  2     4
4  2    n  2     4
```

which works, but is there a more straightforward way to do this?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Use [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#transformation) to add a column back to the orig df from a `groupby` aggregation, `transform` returns a `Series` with its index aligned to the orig df:

```
In [123]:
g = df.groupby('c')['type'].value_counts().reset_index(name='t')
g['size'] = df.groupby('c')['type'].transform('size')
g

Out[123]:
   c type  t  size
0  1    m  1     3
1  1    n  1     3
2  1    o  1     3
3  2    m  2     4
4  2    n  2     4
```

Comment: Actually in this case we should change it to `g['size'] = g.groupby('c')['t'].transform('size')` since I want to keep the `value_counts()`.

Comment: this is a much better answer than: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30244952/python-pandas-create-new-column-with-groupby-sum

Comment: The link to transform has changed slightly, this is the new one: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html#transformation

Answer (score 18):

Another solution with [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) `len`:

```
df['size'] = df.groupby('c')['type'].transform(len)
print df
   c type size
0  1    m    3
1  1    n    3
2  1    o    3
3  2    m    4
4  2    m    4
5  2    n    4
6  2    n    4
```

Another solution with [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) and [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
df['size'] = df['c'].map(df['c'].value_counts())
print (df)
   c type  size
0  1    m     3
1  1    n     3
2  1    o     3
3  2    m     4
4  2    m     4
5  2    n     4
6  2    n     4
```

Comment: Could you please explain shortly why you removed the first part of your original answer? (I found it useful for my goal, which is different from the OP's, but the question's title describes it well (which is how i got here))

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate the groupby object and use it multiple times:

```
g = df.groupby('c')['type']

df = g.value_counts().reset_index(name='counts')
df['size'] = g.transform('size')
```

or

```
g.value_counts().reset_index(name='counts').assign(size=g.transform('size'))
```

Output:

```
   c type  counts  size
0  1    m       1     3
1  1    n       1     3
2  1    o       1     3
3  2    m       2     4
4  2    n       2     4
```