# append specific column value from original DataFrame after groupby - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataframe called `df_engage` its columns are `['district_id', 'time', 'pct_access', 'lp_id']`

| district_id | time | pct_access | lp_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | 2020-01-01 | 3.60 | 93690 |
| 1000 | 2020-01-01 | 0.03 | 17941 |
| 1000 | 2020-01-01 | 0.03 | 65358 |
| 1000 | 2020-01-01 | 0.57 | 98265 |
| 1000 | 2020-01-02 | 41.76 | 59257 |

I have extracted the max pct_access in each day

```
df_engage_max = df_engage.groupby(['district_id', 'time'], as_index=False)['pct_access'].max()
```

the result is:

| district_id | time | pct_access |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | 2020-01-01 | 3.60 |
| 1000 | 2020-01-02 | 41.76 |
| 1000 | 2020-01-03 | 49.76 |

NOW, I need to append column `lp_id` from `df_engage` to `df_engage_max` based on `df_engage_max[['district_id', 'time', 'pct_access']]` that means, the result should be:

| district_id | time | pct_access | lp_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | 2020-01-01 | 3.6 | 93690 |
| 1000 | 2020-01-02 | 41.76 | 59257 |

any help please :) ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pandas add column to groupby dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37189878/pandas-add-column-to-groupby-dataframe)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `idxmax` instead of `max`:

```
# df is df_engage
>>> df.loc[df.groupby(['district_id', 'time'])['pct_access'].idxmax()]

   district_id       time  pct_access  lp_id
0         1000 2020-01-01        3.60  93690
4         1000 2020-01-02       41.76  59257
```

For more explanation, refer to the link posted by @jezrael:

[Get the row(s) which have the max value in groups using groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15705630/get-the-rows-which-have-the-max-value-in-groups-using-groupby)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/15705630

Comment: worked very well and shortcut code, thank you and for reference

Answer (score 0):

Join the 2 tables up.

```
df_engage_max.merge(df_engage, how='inner', on=['district_id', 'time', 'pct_access'])
```

There'll be a few extra columns you will need to drop but that's the gist.

Comment: thanks alot, it works fine, I have tried this solution but my mistake is I wrote
df_engage_max = df_engage_max.merge(df_engage, how='inner', on=['district_id', 'time', 'pct_access'])