# pandas get average of a groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I am trying to find the average monthly cost per user_id but i am only able to get average cost per user or monthly cost per user.

Because i group by user and month, there is no way to get the average of the second groupby (month) unless i transform the groupby output to something else.

This is my df:

```
     df = { 'id' : pd.Series([1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2]),
            'cost' : pd.Series([10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80]),
            'mth': pd.Series([3,3,4,5,3,4,4,5])}

   cost  id  mth
0    10   1    3
1    20   1    3
2    30   1    4
3    40   1    5
4    50   2    3
5    60   2    4
6    70   2    4
7    80   2    5
```

I can get monthly sum but i want the average of the months for each user_id.

```
df.groupby(['id','mth'])['cost'].sum()

id  mth
1   3       30
    4       30
    5       40
2   3       50
    4      130
    5       80
```

i want something like this:

```
id average_monthly
1 (30+30+40)/3
2 (50+130+80)/3
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Resetting the index should work. Try this:

```
In [19]: df.groupby(['id', 'mth']).sum().reset_index().groupby('id').mean()  
Out[19]: 
    mth       cost
id                
1   4.0  33.333333
2   4.0  86.666667
```

You can just drop `mth` if you want. The logic is that after the `sum` part, you have this:

```
In [20]: df.groupby(['id', 'mth']).sum()
Out[20]: 
        cost
id mth      
1  3      30
   4      30
   5      40
2  3      50
   4     130
   5      80
```

Resetting the index at this point will give you unique months.

```
In [21]: df.groupby(['id', 'mth']).sum().reset_index()
Out[21]: 
   id  mth  cost
0   1    3    30
1   1    4    30
2   1    5    40
3   2    3    50
4   2    4   130
5   2    5    80
```

It's just a matter of grouping it again, this time using `mean` instead of `sum`. This should give you the averages.

Let us know if this helps.

Comment: No need to `reset_index`. `df.groupby(['id', 'mth']).sum().groupby(level=0).mean()` will produce the same result.

Comment: How can we assign this back to the original dataframe as a new column? The [transform trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30244979/281545) can't cope with the double group by

Comment: To get the transform, you could first set `id` as the index, then run the `groupby` operations: ``df = df.set_index('id'); df['avg'] = df.groupby(['id','mth']).sum().groupby(level=0).mean()``

Answer (score -1):

```py
df_monthly_average = (
    df.groupby(["InvoiceMonth", "InvoiceYear"])["Revenue"]
    .sum()
    .reset_index()
    .groupby("Revenue")
    .mean()
    .reset_index()
)
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for the answer. Its great that it works for you, but it would help us if you could explain what you did and how did you solve the initial problem!