# Group by Sum as new column name

Tags: python, pandas

I am doing function where I am grouping by ID and summing the $ value associated with those IDs with this code for python:

```
df = df.groupby([' Id'], as_index=False, sort=False)[["Amount"]].sum();
```

but it doesnt rename the column. As such I tried doing this :

```
`df = df.groupby([' Id'], as_index=False, sort=False)`[["Amount"]].sum();.reset_index(name ='Total Amount')
```

but it gave me error that TypeError: reset_index() got an unexpected keyword argument 'name'

So I tried doing this finally following this post:[Python Pandas Create New Column with Groupby().Sum()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30244952/python-pandas-create-new-column-with-groupby-sum)

```
df = df.groupby(['Id'])[["Amount"]].transform('sum');
```

but it still didnt work.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I think you need remove parameter `as_index=False` and use [`Series.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reset_index.html), because this parameter return `df` and then [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) with parameter `name` failed:

```
df = df.groupby('Id', sort=False)["Amount"].sum().reset_index(name ='Total Amount')
```

Or `rename` column first:

```
d = {'Amount':'Total Amount'}
df = df.rename(columns=d).groupby('Id', sort=False, as_index=False)["Total Amount"].sum()
```

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Id':[1,2,2],'Amount':[10, 30,50]})
print (df)
   Amount  Id
0      10   1
1      30   2
2      50   2

df1 = df.groupby('Id', sort=False)["Amount"].sum().reset_index(name ='Total Amount')
print (df1)
   Id  Total Amount
0   1            10
1   2            80

d = {'Amount':'Total Amount'}
df1 = df.rename(columns=d).groupby('Id', sort=False, as_index=False)["Total Amount"].sum()
print (df1)
   Id  Total Amount
0   1            10
1   2            80
```

But if need new column with `sum` in original `df` use [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html) and assign output to new column:

```
df['Total Amount'] = df.groupby('Id', sort=False)["Amount"].transform('sum')
print (df)
   Amount  Id  Total Amount
0      10   1            10
1      30   2            80
2      50   2            80
```

Answer (score 3):

```
import pandas as pd

# set up dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'colA':['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'd'], 
                   'colB':['cat', 'cat', 'dog', 'cat', 'dog', 'cat', 'cat', 'dog'],
                   'colC':[1,2,3,4,4,5,6,7], })

print(df)

  colA colB  colC
0    a  cat     1
1    a  cat     2
2    a  dog     3
3    b  cat     4
4    b  dog     4
5    c  cat     5
6    c  cat     6
7    d  dog     7 



# group on vals in column A
# get min (within groups) for column B 
# get avg (within groups) for column C
df_agg = ( df.groupby(by=['colA'])
          .agg({'colB':'min', 'colC':'mean'})
          .rename(columns={'colB':'colB_grp_min', 'colC':'colC_grp_avg'})
          )

print(df_agg)

     min_colB  avg_colC
colA                   
a         cat       2.0
b         cat       4.0
c         cat       5.5
d         dog       7.0



# if you want multiple aggregations on the same column, pass a list
#   this will return a multiindex
# group on vals in column A
# get min (within groups) for column B 
# get avg and max (within groups) for column C
df_agg2 = ( df.groupby(by=['colA'])
          .agg({'colB':'min', 'colC':['mean', 'max']})
          .rename(columns={'colB':'colB_grp_min', 'colC':'colC_grp_multi_index'})
          )
print(df_agg2)

     colB_grp_min colC_grp_multi_index    
              min                 mean max
colA                                      
a             cat                  2.0   3
b             cat                  4.0   4
c             cat                  5.5   6
d             dog                  7.0   7
```