# Monthly data summary at daily timestep in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have daily time series data in a Pandas dataframe - I'd like to get monthly statistics, but preserve the daily timestep.

```
df = pd.Series(np.arange(365), index=pd.date_range("1900-01-01", periods=365)).to_frame('val')
df_mean = df.resample('M').std().add_suffix('_mth_mean')
```

In this instance, df_mean has a row for each month:

```
            val_mth_mean
1900-01-31          15.0
1900-02-28          44.5
1900-03-31          74.0
```

I'd like those monthly values to be daily, ideally in the same dataframe:

```
            val    val_mth_mean
1900-01-01    0            15.0
1900-01-02    1            15.0 
...
1900-01-31   31            15.0
1900-02-01   32            44.5
1900-02-02   33            44.5
```

Looking for a Pythonic/Pandonic solution without iteration.

Comment: You are looking for `resample` + `transform`: `df['val_mth_mean'] = df.resample('M').transform('mean')`

Comment: Relevant post (with sum instead of mean): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30244952/python-pandas-create-new-column-with-groupby-sum

Comment: Do you need `val` column too? or only `val_mth_mean` with daily.

Comment: I was able to do what I needed (add a column while retaining val) with ALollz's comment.