# Subset of dataframe according to Count value of column

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, subset

Table(df):

```
customer_id    Order_date 
    1       2015-01-16      
    1       2015-01-19      
    2       2014-12-21      
    2       2015-01-10      
    1       2015-01-10
    3       2018-01-18
    3       2017-03-04
    4       2019-11-05
    4       2010-01-01
    3       2019-02-03
    3       2020-01-01
    3       2018-01-01
```

Output needed: A subset of the df where customer_IDs have more than 3 order_dates. (skipping 2,4 and 5 customer ID since they have less than 3 order_dates)

```
 Customer_id  Number_of_Order_dates
     1          3
     3          5
```

I have tried groupby but it has not worked to create a subset. Please help.

Codes tried so far which failed:

```
df[df['days'].count()>3]
```

and one more I tried which is incorrect:

```
 df1=df.groupby('customer_id')['order_date'].count()
 df[df1.iloc[:,1]]
```

Comment: Could you post your `groupby` code attempt?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IIUC

```
df.groupby('customer_id')['Order_date'].nunique().loc[lambda x : x>=3].reset_index()
Out[94]: 
   customer_id  Order_date
0            1           3
1            3           5
```

Comment: this is much much better than mine

Answer (score 4):

You can use:

```
df.groupby('customer_id').filter(lambda x: 
     (x['Order_date'].nunique()>=3)).groupby('customer_id').count()
```

Or:

```
(df[df.groupby('customer_id')['Order_date'].transform('nunique').ge(3)]
   .groupby('customer_id').count())
```

---

```
             Order_date
customer_id            
1                     3
3                     5
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `GroupBy.nunique` with `DataFrame.query`:

```
df.groupby('customer_id')['Order_date'].nunique().reset_index().query('Order_date >= 3')

   customer_id  Order_date
0            1           3
2            3           5
```

Answer (score 1):

#### with `dict`

```
d = {}
for c, o in zip(*map(df.get, df)):
    d.setdefault(c, set()).add(o)

pd.DataFrame(
    [(c, len(o)) for c, o in d.items() if len(o) >= 3],
    columns=[*df]
)

   customer_id  Order_date
0            1           3
1            3           5
```

---

#### with `pd.factorize` and `np.bincount`

```
i, u = df.drop_duplicates().customer_id.factorize()
c = np.bincount(i)

pd.DataFrame(
    [(u_, c_) for u_, c_ in zip(u, c) if c_ > 2],
    columns=[*df]
)

   customer_id  Order_date
0            1           3
1            3           5
```

Answer (score 0):

a brute force approach is to add the groupby as a new column ([pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30244952/how-do-i-create-a-new-column-from-the-output-of-pandas-groupby-sum)), with a name like `num_dates` and then restrict the overall df like this:

`result = my_df[my_df['num_dates'] > 3]`