# Equivalent of Vlookup into return values inside Pandas Dataframe

Tags: pandas

I have this Pandas Dataframe

```
MasterID  product_id  packing_id   Product Name 
1            1                      Apple
1                       1A          
1           1B
1           1C
2                       2A          Banana
3            3                      Orange
3                       3A
4            4                      kiwi
5                       5A          grape
5                       5B
```

I would like like to return a "product family" column. In excel, I would do a Vlookup on the master ID and return the product name in my column.

```
MasterID  product_id  packing_id   Product Name  Product Family
1            1                      Apple          Apple
1                       1A                         Apple
1           1B                                     Apple
1           1C                                     Apple
2                       2A          Banana         Banana
3            3                      Orange         Orange 
3                       3A                         Orange
4            4                      kiwi           Kiwi
5                       5A          grape          grape
5                       5B                         grape
```

How I do this in Python?

Comment: `df['Product Family'] = df.groupby('MasterID')['Product Name'].transform('first')`

Comment: Yep :) you can find similar reference here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/30244952

Answer (score 0):

From @anky

df['Product Family'] = df.groupby('MasterID')['Product Name'].transform('first')