# How do I insert a percentage column in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, percentage

DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['CategoryA', 400], ['CategoryA', 600],
['CategoryB', 1000], ['CategoryB', 2000]],
columns = ['Category', 'ItemTotal'])
```

I used the following to create a groupby for the total dollar amount by category:

```
df = df.groupby('Category') 
df = df['ItemTotal'].sum()
df
```

The output looks like this:

```
Category
CategoryA    1000
CategoryB    3000
```

I want to eventually obtain another column besides the sum for share of each category like so:

```
Category
CategoryA    1000   .25
CategoryB    3000   .75
```

I'd like to know how to do this by inserting the cumulative dollar amount into a new column and then creating a new column for share by dividing.

The link that @jezrael provided [How do I create a new column from the output of pandas groupby().sum()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30244952/how-do-i-create-a-new-column-from-the-output-of-pandas-groupby-sum) returns the sum of each category next to every row in the original data frame:

```
df['Total'] = df['ItemTotal'].groupby(df['Category']).transform('sum')
df
```

Output:

```
   Category     ItemTotal   Total
 0  CategoryA   400         1000
 1  CategoryA   600         1000
 2  CategoryB   1000        3000
 3  CategoryB   2000        3000
```

However, I'm looking for the sum of each category and the share of the total next to **each unique category** that has been grouped, not every row in the original dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First is necessary convert `index` to column:

```
df1 = df.groupby('Category', as_index=False)['ItemTotal'].sum()
```

Or:

```
df1 = df.groupby('Category')['ItemTotal'].sum().reset_index()
```

If need convert `Series` to one column `DataFrame`:

```
df1 = df.groupby('Category')['ItemTotal'].sum().to_frame()
```

And last divide `sum` of column:

```
df1['Perc'] = df1['ItemTotal'].div(df1['ItemTotal'].sum())
print (df1)
    Category  ItemTotal  Perc
0  CategoryA       1000  0.25
1  CategoryB       3000  0.75
```