# Group by to return entirety of the data not just what I am grouping by

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

Is it possible to return the entirety of data not just part of which we are grouping by?

I mean for example - I have a dataframe with 5 columns and one of those columns contains `distance`, the other one is `timestamp` and the last important one is `name`. I grouped dataframe by `timestamp` - agg function I applied is `(min) on distance`. As a return i get correctly grouped dataframe with timestamp and distance - how can i add columns `name` there. If I group it by `name` as well then `timestamp` becomes duplicated - it has to stay **unique**. As a final result I need to get dataframe like this:

| timestamp | name | distance |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-03-03 15:30:235 | Billy | 123 |
| 2020-03-03 15:30:435 | Johny | 111 |

But instead i get this:

| timestamp | distance |
| --- | --- |
| 2020-03-03 15:30:235 | 123 |
| 2020-03-03 15:30:435 | 111 |

Whole table has more than 700k rows so joining it back on `distance` gives me that amount of rows which my PC can't even handle.

Here is my `groupby` which gives me 2nd table:

`grouped_df = df1.groupby('timestamp')['distance'].min()`

Here is what i tried to do in order to get `name` inside the table:

```
grouped_df.merge(df1, how='left', left_on=['timestamp','distance'],    
right_on = ['timestamp','distance'])
```

Comment: can you post the relevant lines of your code? then it'll be easy

Comment: i just uploaded the code @RusJ

Comment: i hope this will answer your problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30244952/how-do-i-create-a-new-column-from-the-output-of-pandas-groupby-sum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try

```
out = df.sort_values('distance').drop_duplicates('timestamp')
```

Then try with `transform`

```
m = df.groupby('timestamp')['distance'].transform('min')
dout = df[df.distance==m]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**`GroupBy.agg`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) method to apply `min` on the **distance** column, and apply a relevant function on **name** column (`lambda x:x` to simply return its data). This will return the dataframe with both columns back to you:

```
grouped_df = df1.groupby('timestamp').agg({'distance':'min','name':lambda x:x})
```

Also if you want **timestamp** back as a column and not as index, you can set `as_index=False` during groupby.

**Output:**

```
>>> grouped_df = df1.groupby('timestamp', as_index=False).agg({'distance':'min','name':lambda x:x})
>>> grouped_df
              timestamp  distance   name
0  2020-03-03 15:30:235       123  Billy
1  2020-03-03 15:30:435       111  Johny
```

Comment: Hi, thanks. Thought it doesn't return entire dataframe, column name is still not returned. It gives only timestamp and distance but doesnt show the person who did the distance.

Comment: ohh Yes, posted code too early, you can apply a relevant function on name column as well. Edited the answer, try now.