# Add a new column with sum of values divided by unique value within groups in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe such as ::

```
Group COL1 COL2 
G1    30   500
G1    21   500 
G1    43   500 
G2    89   677
G2    78   900 
G3    32   322
G3    90   200
```

and I would like to add a new column called `mean_group` where I calculate for each `Group`, the sum of `COL1`/unique value of `COL2`.For instance, `(30+21+43)/500 = 0.188`

```
I should then get:  
Group COL1 COL2 mean_group
G1    30   500  0.188
G1    21   500  0.188
G1    43   500  0.188
G2    89   677  0.2466765
G2    78   677  0.2466765
G3    32   322  0.09937888
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30244952/how-do-i-create-a-new-column-from-the-output-of-pandas-groupby-sum This is similar concept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do this

```
df['mean_group']=df.groupby('Group')['COL1'].transform('sum')/df['COL2']
```

output:

```
  Group  COL1  COL2  mean_group
0    G1    30   500    0.188000
1    G1    21   500    0.188000
2    G1    43   500    0.188000
3    G2    89   677    0.246677
4    G2    78   900    0.185556
5    G3    32   322    0.378882
6    G3    90   200    0.610000
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
df['mean_group'] = df.groupby('Group')['COL1'].transform('mean')/df['COL2']
```