# data proccesing to make total payment python

Tags: python, pandas, data-processing

| Nama | No.ID | Tgl/Waktu | No.PIN | Kode Verifikasi |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Alif | 100061 | 17/12/2022 07:53:26 |  | Sidik Jari |
| Alif | 100061 | 17/12/2022 13:00:25 |  | Sidik Jari |
| Alif | 100061 | 19/12/2022 07:54:59 |  | Sidik Jari |
| Alif | 100061 | 19/12/2022 16:18:14 |  | Sidik Jari |
| Alif | 100061 | 20/12/2022 07:55:54 |  | Sidik Jari |
| Alif | 100061 | 20/12/2022 16:16:16 |  | Sidik Jari |
| Alif | 100061 | 21/12/2022 07:54:46 |  | Sidik Jari |
| Alif | 100061 | 21/12/2022 16:15:41 |  | Sidik Jari |
| Alif | 100061 | 22/12/2022 07:55:54 |  | Sidik Jari |
| Alif | 100061 | 22/12/2022 16:15:59 |  | Sidik Jari |
| Alif | 100061 | 23/12/2022 07:56:26 |  | Sidik Jari |
| Alif | 100061 | 23/12/2022 16:16:56 |  | Sidik Jari |
| budi | 100063 | 17/12/2022 07:45:28 |  | Sidik Jari |
| budi | 100063 | 17/12/2022 13:00:23 |  | Sidik Jari |
| budi | 100063 | 19/12/2022 07:39:29 |  | Sidik Jari |
| budi | 100063 | 19/12/2022 16:17:37 |  | Sidik Jari |
| budi | 100063 | 20/12/2022 13:13:06 |  | Sidik Jari |
| budi | 100063 | 20/12/2022 16:16:14 |  | Sidik Jari |
| budi | 100063 | 21/12/2022 07:39:54 |  | Sidik Jari |
| budi | 100063 | 21/12/2022 16:15:38 |  | Sidik Jari |
| budi | 100063 | 22/12/2022 07:39:02 |  | Sidik Jari |
| budi | 100063 | 22/12/2022 16:15:55 |  | Sidik Jari |
| budi | 100063 | 23/12/2022 07:41:13 |  | Sidik Jari |
| budi | 100063 | 23/12/2022 16:16:25 |  | Sidik Jari |

so from that raw excel file i want to make a app to output the waging system

```
!pip install xlrd
import pandas as pd
from datetime import time, timedelta
import openpyxl

from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')

# Read the Excel file
path = '/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/Book1.xlsx'
df = pd.read_excel(path)


# Convert the 'Tgl/Waktu' column to datetime format
df['Tgl/Waktu'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Tgl/Waktu'])

# Extract the date and time from the 'Tgl/Waktu' column
df['Date'] = df['Tgl/Waktu'].dt.date
df['Time'] = df['Tgl/Waktu'].dt.time

# Group the data by employee name and date
grouped_df = df.groupby(['Nama', 'Date'])

# Set the overtime threshold to 16:30:00
overtime_threshold = time(hour=16, minute=30)

# Iterate over the grouped data
for (name, date), group in grouped_df:
    # Calculate the total work hours and overtime hours for each employee on each day
    start_time = group['Time'].min()
    end_time = group['Time'].max()
    total_hours = (timedelta(hours=end_time.hour, minutes=end_time.minute, seconds=end_time.second) - 
                   timedelta(hours=start_time.hour, minutes=start_time.minute, seconds=start_time.second)).total_seconds() / 3600
    if total_hours > 8:
        hours_worked = 8
        if end_time > overtime_threshold:
          overtime_hours += (end_time - overtime_threshold).total_seconds() / 3600
    else:
        hours_worked = total_hours
        overtime_hours = 0
    if end_time > overtime_threshold:
        overtime_hours += (end_time - overtime_threshold).total_seconds() / 3600
    # Calculate the payment for each employee on each day
    payment_each_date = 75000 * hours_worked + 50000 * overtime_hours
    
       # Add the total work hours, overtime hours, and payment as new columns to the dataframe
    df.loc[(df['Nama'] == name) & (df['Date'] == date), 'Hours Worked'] = hours_worked
    df.loc[(df['Nama'] == name) & (df['Date'] == date), 'Overtime Hours'] = overtime_hours
    df.loc[(df['Nama'] == name) & (df['Date'] == date), 'Payment Each Date'] = payment_each_date

# Print the resulting dataframe
print(df)

# write DataFrame to excel
df.to_excel(excel_writer=r'/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/test.xlsx')
```

from that code i want to add another column that is total payment, i have an idea to add payment each date thats grouped by name and with different date

how do i do that?

i already try used groupby nama then sum the payment each day but its still error

Comment: Please include the `total_payment` code you've tried. Once you've calculated `Payment Each Date` to the `df`, you can use `groupby` again on `Nama` only, sum the `Payment Each Date` column, then join the total df you get with the original `df` on the `Nama` column they have in common

Comment: If you provide a minimum reproducible example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), I can help with that but the current example is a little too difficult to work with

Comment: Is it expected that your example has no cases with overtime?

Comment: in my data, there is no overtime cases, but it is required to have that feature @DamianSatterthwaite-Phillips

Comment: `grouped_df = df.groupby(['Nama'])`

`df['Total Payment'] = grouped_df['Payment Each Date'].apply(lambda x: x.sum())`

@frederick-douglas-pearce

Comment: Ok, I think I see the issue you're having. There is only one row per `Nama` value in the `Total Payment` column so you can't add it to the original `df` like this since it has many rows for each `Nama` value. I will post an answer with a possible solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

If you want to remove duplicate `date` rows prior to calculating the total payment for each `Nama` value, then first group by `Nama` and `date`, take the max value (min is the same as the two values are equal), group that result by `Nama` and sum the `Payment Each Date` values. This produces a series with the total payment for each `Nama`, `s_total`, which can then be joined to the original dataframe to obtain the desired `Total Payment` column:

```
s_total = df.groupby(['Nama', 'Date'])['Payment Each Date'].max().groupby('Nama').sum().rename('Total Payment')
df = df.merge(s_total, how='left', on='Nama')
```

Left join is safer as that will always keep all rows of `df` just in case.

Updated Output `df`:

[image]

**Original Answer**

If you just want to sum all the `Payment Each Date` values in a new column, then add the following line of code after the `for` loop code block and before the line that prints the df:

```
df['Total Payment'] = df.groupby('Nama')['Payment Each Date'].transform('sum')
```

The `transform` takes care of aligning the indices of the series containing the sum for each `Nama` value with the original df.

Original Output `df`:
[image]

This SO post has some similar answers: [How do I create a new column from the output of pandas groupby().sum()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30244952/how-do-i-create-a-new-column-from-the-output-of-pandas-groupby-sum)

Comment: from your answer it adds all the payment each date, but the row is for the time in and out. so I need to sum the different payment each date to make the total payment (I know I can divide the total by 2 but probably there's a better answer more than that)

Comment: Ok, I understand what you mean. I can modify the code