# In python, using pandas groupby to calculate mean value, but the results are all Nan

Tags: python, pandas, mean

This is how I calculate the mean by the group:
[image]

I need to calculate the group mean value of the 'volatility'. The group is 'code_YM'. But the results of mean volatility,'stock_volatility',

[image] are all nan. Could u help me to fix this?

The type of 'volatility' is float. The type of 'code_YM' is string. I dont know why the results are all nan. I hope the result of mean value could be float.

Comment: Show code and other textual information as properly formatted text in the question, not as comment, image or external link. For the resulting table an image should be ok.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create a new column from the output of pandas groupby().sum()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30244952/how-do-i-create-a-new-column-from-the-output-of-pandas-groupby-sum)

Comment: use `transform` -- `df['some_col'] = df.groupby('col')['other_col'].transform('mean')`

Comment: You original `.mean()` produces a Series with the mean values for each Group. You attempt to form a new DF column from the (shorter) Series but clearly they can't be directly assigned as different lengths. `.transform` is provided to map the grouped results across to the original DF.

Answer (score 0):

As others suggested, this probably happens because the result of the groupby(...).mean() is a shorter vector of numbers and you are trying to create a full column while inserting a shorter vector than it is needed.

The solution to this is using "transform":

```
data_volatility['stock_v'] = data_volatility.groupby('code_YM')['volatility'].transform('mean')
```

Other possibilities are:

1. There is a nan value in the "volatility" column, at least one for each group.
   Make sure there are no nan values in that column:

   ```
   print(pd.isna(data_volatility['volatility']).mean())
   ```

Will result in the % of Nan/null/None values in that column. make sure it's 0.

2. the volatility column is not a numeric column, perhaps you read a text file and the reading function didn't find it numeric (maybe a string)