# how to add new column to pandas dataframe with groupby and sum?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to do like this [How do I create a new column from the output of pandas groupby().sum()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30244952/how-do-i-create-a-new-column-from-the-output-of-pandas-groupby-sum)

as show in the high scored answer,
df['Data4'] = f['Data3'].groupby(df['Date']).transform('sum')

however, I want to groupby two columns.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do `df['Data4'] = df.groupby(['Date', 'second_grouping_column'])['Data3'].transform('sum')`. As you can see on [this page](https://jamesrledoux.com/code/group-by-aggregate-pandas), the groupby method can take a list of columns

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).