# Groupby and count() with alias and 'normal' dataframe: python pandas versus mssql

Tags: sql-server, pandas, pandas-groupby

Coming from a SQL environment, I am learning some things in Python Pandas. I have a question regarding grouping and aggregates.

Say I group a dataset by Age Category and count the different categories. In MSSQL I would write this:

```
SELECT AgeCategory, COUNT(*) AS Cnt
FROM TableA
GROUP BY AgeCategory
ORDER BY 1
```

The result set is a 'normal' table with two columns, the second column I named Count.

When I want to do the equivalent in Pandas, the groupby object is different in format. So now I have to reset the index and rename the column in a following line. My code would look like this:

```
grouped = df.groupby('AgeCategory')['ColA'].count().reset_index()
grouped.columns = ['AgeCategory', 'Count']
grouped
```

My question is if this can be accomplished in one go. Seems like I am over-doing it, but I lack experience.

Thanks for any advise.

Regards, M.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas create new column with count from groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29836477/pandas-create-new-column-with-count-from-groupby)

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55435185, titled "**Count ALL Rows per Group (Series/DataFrame): GroupBy.size**" (getting count in groupby, count v/s size... scroll down)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use parameter `name` in [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
grouped = df.groupby('AgeCategory')['ColA'].count().reset_index(name='Count')
```

Or:

```
grouped = df.groupby('AgeCategory').size().reset_index(name='Count')
```

Difference is [`GroupBy.count`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.count.html) exclude missing values, [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) not.

---

More information about [aggregation in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53781634/aggregation-in-pandas).