# Convert dataframe column values to column names and display count

Tags: python, dataframe

```
rules       close_time
100670   December-2019
100670   November-2019
100664   December-2019
100670   November-2019
100670   December-2019
100664   December-2019
100664   November-2019
```

Here's how I want it.
The total count should be displayed per rule for each month.

```
rules    December-2019   November-2019
100670               2               2
100664               2               1
```

Comment: In my opinion you should look at solution below: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29836477/pandas-create-new-column-with-count-from-groupby .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just want a pivot table with the count for the values.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
 'rules': [100670, 100670, 100664, 100670, 100670, 100664, 100664],
 'close_time': ['December-2019', 'November-2019', 'December-2019', 'November-2019',
                'December-2019', 'December-2019', 'November-2019']
})
df.pivot_table(index='rules', columns=['close_time'], aggfunc=len)
# returns:
close_time  December-2019  November-2019
rules
100664                  2              1
100670                  2              2
```

If you want `rules` to be a column and not an index, you can use:

```
df.pivot_table(
    index='rules', 
    columns=['close_time'], 
    aggfunc=len
).reset_index().rename_axis(columns={'close_time': None})
# returns:
    rules  December-2019  November-2019
0  100664              2              1
1  100670              2              2
```

Comment: Getting this error - TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Comment: Does copying and pasting my example (including the `df` assignment) not work for you?

Comment: still getting the error - TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Comment: What version of pandas as you running?  `pd.__version__`

Comment: pandas version 0.25.3

Comment: I have the same version.  Maybe restart python?

Comment: Boy that is weird.  I can copy and paste this into a new python instance and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to do it:

```
df = df.groupby(['rules','close_time']).size().unstack()
df.index.name = None

close_time  December-2019  November-2019
100664                  2              1
100670                  2              2
```