# Groupby upon multiple columns, then append

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

i am trying to count the number of occurrences of the same packet in my dataframe, a packet is the same if it has these matching fields:

```
['SourceIP', 'SourcePort', 'DestinationIP', 'DestinationPort', 'Protocol']
```

I want to make a new column in my dataframe with the occurrence values and have this column be called 'PerSec'

I have tried to implement the solution to this problem found here [Pandas create new column with count from groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29836477/pandas-create-new-column-with-count-from-groupby)

However when I run:

```
df['PerSec'] = df.groupby(['SourceIP', 'SourcePort', 'DestinationIP', 'DestinationPort', 'Protocol']['SourceIP', 'SourcePort', 'DestinationIP', 'DestinationPort', 'Protocol'].transform('PerSec'))
with pd.option_context('display.max_rows', None, 'display.max_columns', None):
    print(df)
```

I receive this error:

> TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple

Does this mean the groupby method will only work upon one column?

Comment: your index should be a list.so groupby([...])[[...]] note the double brackets

Comment: can you give a small sample of your data? but one though might be to pick a sngle column outside your groupers, call it `countcol` say, and then stick `['countcol']` between the groupby and the transform.

Comment: and I think you want `count` inside the transform if I am reading your question correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add only one column after `groupby` and pass to `groupby` some aggregate function, e.g. [`GroupBy.count`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.count.html):

```
cols = ['SourceIP', 'SourcePort', 'DestinationIP', 'DestinationPort', 'Protocol']
df['PerSec'] = df.groupby(cols)['SourceIP'].transform('count')
```

Answer (score 0):

Groupby method can be extended to multiple columns. It will group in the given order of columns

in you case

```
df.groupby(['SourceIP', 'SourcePort', 'DestinationIP', 'DestinationPort', 'Protocol'])
```

will return a grouped dataframe in which if SourceIP equals it groups by SourcePort and so on.

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this

```
df['PerSec'] = df.groupby([['SourceIP', 'SourcePort', 'DestinationIP', 'DestinationPort', 'Protocol']])['SourceIP', 'SourcePort', 'DestinationIP', 'DestinationPort', 'Protocol'].transform('PerSec')
```